# WPF Label Content Display During Execution

Tags: wpf, events, label

Sorry, I'm a novice when it comes to WPF:

When I click a button, I would like to see the one message displayed in a label when the function starts, and then I would like to see another message displayed when the function completes.

In the code here, I only see the last message value displayed when the button is clicked.  Can someone explain to me why?

Since this doesn't work, how would I go about accomplishing what I really want - to see one message for some time (like "processing"), and then another message (like "complete") when the function completes?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageLabel.Content = "I never see this";

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        MessageLabel.Content = "I only see this";
    }
}
```

---

Thank you Blachshma!  Here is the code that does what I want with the BackgroundWorker object.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;

        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageLabel.Content = "I see this now";

        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); 
        }
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageLabel.Content = "and I see this too";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't see a change is because this is all run on the UI thread, which doesn't have a chance to refresh your screen until *after* the second time the label is updated.
You should use a **[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)** to run the "heavy" part of your code (e.g. the Sleep + update of the label)

Quick example with your code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageLabel.Content = "I never see this";

    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (s,a) =>
          {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
          };
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) =>
          {
                MessageLabel.Content = "I saw it now";
          };
    bw.RunWorkerAsync(); // Start BackgroundWorker
```